# Change InputType from None to Multi Line

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, multiline, android-inputtype

I've disabled edit text view in the XML and What I'm trying to do is enable it again using the code. What I want is a multi-line edit box and while entering the text it should suggest dictionary words. I've written the following code, it enables the edit text box but the input type isn't changing.

```
EditText messageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        messageText.setFocusable(true);
        messageText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        messageText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
        messageText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE);
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Do this,

```
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
edit.setEnabled(false);
edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
edit.setFocusable(false);
```

And when any other option selected do this,

```
edit.setEnabled(true);
edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
edit.setFocusable(true);
```

answer on stackoverflow as it is